# ImagXpress and C# - Placing Stamp on Image through ImagXpress

Tags: c#, image, watermark

I'm having trouble with trying to place a stamp on an image through AccuSoft's ImagXpress.  If I access the properties in C#, I get a width and height for the Image frame, but the height and width for the image is the actual height and width in pixels so it is much larger than what is displayed on the screen.

Does anyone have experience with ImagXpress and placing a stamp or watermark on an image through it before it prints?  I have tried placing it by converting from pixels to twips when it prints but it does not convert correctly since I have so many different size measurements (frame in pixels, ACTUAL file size in pixels, print job paperwidth in twips).

Or does anyone know where I could find more information on how to accomplish this?  I tried to visit AccuSoft's site but they don't appear to have forums, only the manual and FAQ's which didn't really help all that much.

Answer (score 0):

Having just spent a lot of effort on this, here is what I came up with. It puts a stamp on each page in a multipage tif image.

```
public class AccusoftStamper
{
    public string Stamp()
    {
            var fileNameOrStream = ... // Get your image from somewhere

            using (var lifetime = AccusoftProvider.ImagXpress) // Replace this with your own license
            {
                var load = new LoadOptions();

                // All my images are multipage tiff files
                var save = new SaveOptions { Format = ImageXFormat.Tiff };
                save.Tiff.MultiPage = true;

                using (ImageX image = ImageX.FromFile(lifetime, fileNameOrStream, load))
                {
                    int offset = 0;
                    int pages = ImageX.NumPages(lifetime, fileNameOrStream);
                    for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
                    {
                        image.Page = i + 1;
                        save.Tiff.Compression = image.ImageXData.Compression;

                        var pageStamp = ".." // Get your stamp
                        StampImage(lifetime, pageStamp, image);

                        save.Tiff.UseIFDOffset = offset > 0;
                        save.Tiff.IFDOffset = offset;

                        image.Save(outputFileName, save);

                        offset = save.Tiff.IFDOffset;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private void StampImage(ImagXpress lifetime, string text, ImageX destination)
    {
        using (var processor = new Processor(lifetime, destination))
        {
            int bitsPerPixel = destination.ImageXData.BitsPerPixel;
            if (bitsPerPixel != 24) // we can only paint on a 24 bit image.
                processor.ColorDepth(24, PaletteType.Optimized, DitherType.NoDither);


            using (var g = destination.GetGraphics())
            using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 16, FontStyle.Bold))
            using (var matrix = new Matrix())
            {
                try
                {
                    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);
                    Point location = GetStampLocation(new Size(destination.ImageXData.Width, destination.ImageXData.Height), textSize);

                    // All my stamping is vertically along the left edge
                    matrix.Translate(1, 1);
                    matrix.RotateAt(-90, new PointF(location.X, location.Y));
                    g.Transform = matrix;

                    g.DrawString(text,
                                 font,
                                 Brushes.Black,
                                 location.X, location.Y,
                                 new StringFormat());
                }
                finally
                {
                    destination.ReleaseGraphics();
                }
            }
            // The BPP may change accoding to Accusofts documentation, so change it back to what is was
            if (bitsPerPixel != destination.ImageXData.BitsPerPixel)
                processor.ColorDepth(bitsPerPixel, PaletteType.Optimized, DitherType.NoDither);
        }
    }

    public Point GetStampLocation(Size imageSize, SizeF textSize)
    {
        var p = new Point(0, 0);

        // Top Right
        //p.X += destination.ImageXData.Width;

        // Top left
        //p.Y += (int)Math.Round(textSize.Width, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        // Need to figure out where you want the stamp to be

        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use AccusoftProvider.ImagXpress, what is that?  I'm not sure what you mean by use your own license.  I'm not super familiar with ImagXpress as it was already implemented when I started work on this.

Comment: Also, when does this happen during program use?  I believe our goal was to have them place an area on their image while viewing it which would indicate where on the page the stamp would go.

Comment: That is the property I use for instantiating the ImagXpress object, which is responsible for verifying your license. See http://help.accusoft.com/ImagXpress/v12.0/dotnet/Accusoft.ImagXpress12.Net~Accusoft.ImagXpressSdk.ImagXpress.html

Comment: As for your second comment, it sounds like you would run this step after a user selects an image and a location, you translate that to a coordinate in pixels, stamp, and then display the updated version.